# Xcode parsing error of json returned from php

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm trying to use PHP to fetch data from a MySQL server. Below is the PHP file content:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$dbc=mysql_connect("host", "defaultuser", "defaultuser");
mysql_select_db("customer");
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer_infor";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id_index=$line['id_index'];
$first_name=$line['first_name'];
$last_name=$line['last_name'];

$customers[]=array('id_index'=>$id_index, 'first_name'=>$first_name, 'last_name'=>$last_name);

}
$response['customers']=$customers;

echo json_encode($response);
mysql_close($dbc);
?>
```

The PHP script returned the json result as below:

```
{"customers":[{"id_index":"1","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Johnson"}, {"id_index":"2","first_name":"Bill","last_name":"Harrison"},{"id_index":"3","first_name":"Julie","last_name":"Johns"}]}
```

When I try to use Xcode to receive the json string and parse it use the following code:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.connectionData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSString *retString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.connectionData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

    NSError *parseError = nil;

    self.dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.connectionData options:0 error:&parseError];
    if (!parseError) {

        NSLog(@"json array is %@", self.dataArray);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSString *err = [parseError localizedDescription];
        NSLog(@"Encountered error parsing: %@", err);
    }  
    connection = nil;
    self.connectionData = nil;
}
```

This Xcode script is in a view controller. When the json data is returned, it is firstly put into `self.connectionData`, which is then parsed by `NSJSONSerialization`. The data are finally put into `self.dataArray`.
I was expecting that there are 3 elements in the dataArray, for the three customers. However, the `NSLog` and system debugging both indicate only one element in the array. This error prevents me from further putting the customer data into a table view.

Can anybody help me find the solution to this problem?

Comment: `self.dataArray` is a dictionary, its `valueForKey:@"customers"` is an array.

Comment: Or its `objectForKey`. Or `self.dataArray[@"customers"]`.

Comment: Xcode is just a fancy editor/compiler. It is your app that does the above work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dataReturned = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.connectionData options:0 error:&parseError];
self.dataArray = dataReturned[@"customers"];
if (!parseError) {

    NSLog(@"json array is %@", self.dataArray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} else {
    NSString *err = [parseError localizedDescription];
    NSLog(@"Encountered error parsing: %@", err);
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Man! It works perfect! NSDictionary vs. NSArray is always confusing to me.....